# MATLAB float accuracy

Tags: matlab, floating-accuracy

I want to check numerical stability of QR algorithm, for this i need to create matrix like this:

```
 S = diag(2.^(-1:-1:-80));
```

But it has rank 46, i think it is because of lack of accuracy. But in the book i'm reading it is full ranked matrix. How can i increase accuracy of computations?

Comment: @lakesh , `format long` is about output accuracy not internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/symbolic/vpa.html) (variable precision ariuthmetic):

```
>> S = diag(2.^vpa((-1:-1:-80)), 100); %// 100 here is number of precision digits
>> rank(S)
ans =
    80
```

Note that the result is of type `sym`. Convert to `double` if needed:

```
>> double(rank(S))
ans =
    80
```